# I would expect this useRef and useEffect combo to fail...why does it succeed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would expect this `useEffect` to fail on the first render, since I would assume the `innerCarouselRef.current` would be undefined on the first render and it makes a call to `getBoundingClientRect`. Why does it work/why is the `innerCarouselRef.current` defined when the `useEffect` runs?

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { debounce } from 'lodash';

 export default function Carousel({ RenderComponent }) {
  const [innerCarouselWidth, setInnerCarouselWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const [itemWidth, setItemWidth] = React.useState(0);
  const innerCarouselRef = useRef();
  const itemRef = useRef();
  const content = data.map((el, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={`item-${i}`} ref={i === 0 ? itemRef : undefined}>
        <RenderComponent {...el} />
      </div>
    );
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const getElementWidths = () => {
      setInnerCarouselWidth(innerCarouselRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width); // why doesn't this call to getBoundingClientRect() break?
      setItemWidth(itemRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    };
    getElementWidths();
    const debouncedListener = debounce(getElementWidths, 500);
    window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedListener);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', debouncedListener);
  }, []);
 return (
    <div className="inner-carousel" ref={innerCarouselRef}>
      {content}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React runs the effects after it has updated the DOM (we typically want it to work that way). In your case, the effect runs after the component has mounted and so `innerCarouselRef.current` is set.

I would recommend reading the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-without-cleanup) docs to gain a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks! I'm familiar with the useEffect docs...but I also wonder why wouldn't I need to use `useLayoutEffect` since I am taking a DOM measurement here? Why does `useLayoutEffect` even exist if I can take a DOM measurement perfectly fine using `useEffect`?

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` will run before the browser paints the DOM to the screen, `useEffect` will run **after**.

Comment: @brianyates Ivan is right. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect): `useLayoutEffect` fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. **Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint**. Prefer the standard `useEffect` when possible to avoid blocking visual updates." Thanks, Ivan!

Comment: Understood. Thanks, gents.